# Killing a userspace program from a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am just wondering if there is a way to kill a userspace program from a kernel module.I know that kill command won't work as it is a system call from userspace to kernel space.

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-send-a-signal-from-a-module-to-a-process-803485/

Answer (score 5):

This code will kill the calling process...

```
int signum = SIGKILL;
task = current;
struct siginfo info;
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
info.si_signo = signum;
int ret = send_sig_info(signum, &info, task);
if (ret < 0) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "error sending signal\n");
}
```

You can see how the OOM killer does it here...

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/oom_kill.c?v=3.16#L516

Comment: If I know the name of the userspace program, for example "xyz", I want to send a signal to that process from a kernel module. Looks like the code above kills the current process.

Comment: You need to find the `task`, then send a signal to it.

Comment: You should use `send_sig_info(SIGKILL, SEND_SIG_PRIV, task);` Using SEND_SIG_PRIV also avoids a check for newer kernels, which use `kernel_siginfo` instead of `siginfo`

Answer (score 0):

If you know what syscall can be used by userspace to deliver signals, why can't you check how it is implemented? More importantly though, why do you think you need to send a signal in the first place? How do you determine what to signal in the first place?

Is this another beyond terrible college assignment?